# Device gets REGISTRATION intent whenever I send a C2DM message to it - not a RECEIVE intent

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have C2DM setup following all the online docs and tutorials.  My device successfully registers itself, and stores the registrationId.

When I request registration, the device gets a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER intent.

I then pass this registrationId to my server and send a C2DM message to it, which goes off successfully, returning a messageId.

**Now the problem is after I send the message, the device gets a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER intent, and NOT a com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE intent.**

This intent has the EXTRA of EXTRA_UNREGISTERED - so within handleRegistration() it then clears the registrationId.

I cannot figure this out for the life of me.  My code is pretty much identical to the ChromeToPhone demo.

Comment: First the server might not sending the Notifications if sending can add the code for your C2DM

Comment: I am testing with simple curl commands that return a messageId.  This leads me to believe server is sending without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may have been caused by a problem in AndroidManifest.xml - despite checking it 20x times.

I had

```
<permission android:name="co.sample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="co.sample.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

**Notice the name of the permission does not match.**  Be advised that many features of C2DM can work and work strangely with small Manifest problems.